java spring boot entity uuid randomize returns value existing
I have an entity like this
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="userrank", indexes = { @Index(name = "tourIDmatchID", columnList = "tournamentId, userId")})
public class Userrank {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private java.util.UUID id;
    Long userIid;
    int score;
    Long tournamentId;
}

and I only give it an @id because I have to. Otherwise spring boot fails; I will almost never use the UUID field.
When I create a Userrank with a constructor, I use random UUID like this:
Userrank userrank = new Userrank(UUID.randomUUID(), val1, val2, val3);

I will have millions of entries to this table. Is it possible that UUID.randomUUID() somehow happens to return a UUID already existing in the table, then would it return an error while trying to insert with .save() method ?

It is possible in theory that UUID.randomUUID() can return a duplicate UUID twice, but in practice, it's considered an impossibility. Even if your table had quadrillions of records, you would never have to fear a UUID collision.
As for your specific issue: since you are using the @GeneratedValue annotation, you shouldn't need to provide UUID on your own. The annotation should automatically populate this value with a random UUID. I would try using no-args constructor to construct your objects, and set the value of other columns using setters, and see if your issue goes away.
Finally I'll add that it is ALWAYS good practice to have a non-null primary key on your database tables, even if you think it might not be necessary, and using UUIDs as primary keys is always a good choice as well.
